# how to fix Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'

Tags: java, android

When I sign my Android app it gives this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not find lint-gradle-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/27.1.0/lint-gradle-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/27.1.0/lint-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-checks-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/27.1.0/lint-checks-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-api-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/27.1.0/lint-api-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find intellij-core-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/27.1.0/intellij-core-27.1.0.jar
   
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.0-alpha01-6193524/aapt2-proto-4.1.0-alpha01-6193524.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

And when I add this to my app:

```
lintOptions {
    quiet true
    // Whether lint should set the exit code of the process if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // Returns whether lint will only check for errors (ignoring warnings)
    ignoreWarnings true
    // Returns whether lint should check for fatal errors during release builds. Default is true.
    // If issues with severity "fatal" are found, the release build is aborted.
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
```

then there is no error, but APK won't install on my phone.

Comment: find any solution ?

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly your problem:

- Exit Android Studio
- Delete gradle caches folder located `C:\Users\{USER}\.gradle\caches`
- Run Android Studio and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too ! I just deleted these files :

```
project_folder/.gradle
project_folder/.idea
project_folder/.gradle
project_folder/build
project_folder/app/build
project_folder/app/release
C:\\users\Your_Name\.gradle\caches
```

Then open Android Studio & execute again .